# Jersey client side Exception handler

Tags: java, jersey-client

Im using jersey for my javafx application client side.
Server side is implemented using Spring boot.
I want to implement a filter so i can map exceptions from server to my own exceptions.
but using ClientResponseFilter i cannot get response content to convert it to my own exception type.

```
public class ExceptionFilter implements ClientResponseFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, 
     ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
     {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() != 
                 Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
              // here i need to get response content!
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the content use getReasonPhrase().
In your case responseContext.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase();
This will return content String.